# How can one stop brakes from screeching?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, brakes, noise

I'm hearing that annoying sound when you use your brakes and you get the chills from the screeching sound.

I have disk brakes and a relatively new bike.

It happens to be front tire shown below.  I checked for contaminant and none exists.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with brake discs](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/10972/problems-with-brake-discs) - a several other questions. Please use the search function.

Comment: my bike has not been recently serviced and there is no visible contaminant on the brakes.

Comment: The answers to "My disc is squealing" is the same regardless -  Adjust the calipers, clean the disk/pads, replace the pads with organics. Contamination is often not visible, Oil from fingers touching the disk can be enough to cause squealing.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  The other OP took his bike in to a shop were they seemed to obviously contaminate the brakes.  Not my case.   This is a new bike with no contaminant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sand both the brake disk and the brake pad.  The screeching sound is caused because the surfaces are too smooth.

Comment: Is this really the accepted answer ? The bike is new, who in a clear frame of mind would start sanding the disks and pads down.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend swizzstop discbrake silencer, and sand the surface if the brake pads with fine sandpaper.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider expanding your answer to tell us a bit more about Swizzstop Discbrake Silencer. What is it? How do you use it? Why this product over others? A short, one-line answer like this is likely to get downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.

Comment: Have not tried it - a couple of reviews claim it reduces braking power. Morgan Blue Disc Brake Paste Silencer is another product could be worth a try,